# Not getting output after dmesg

Tags: programming

I am a beginner. I wrote a hello world module (actually copied from the o'Reilly book).
the code is:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "\nHello World");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "\nGood bye");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

So when i insert the module, and dmesg nothig would appear. But when i remove it, and then dmesg, i can see

```
Hello World

Good Bye
```

Comment: Please always include the actual commands you ran. What's the "hello world module"? Did you write it? Did you check `/var/log/kern.log`? Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: I hope you know it is better to use `grep` to search for text in files such as `/var/log/syslog` and outputs of `dmesg`.

Comment: The proper site for such questions is [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the buffer is not cleared when you print "\nHello world" and cleared when ultimately you remove the module.

To deliberately clear the buffer, instead print

```
Hello world\n
```

and similarly,

```
Good bye\n
```

Note the newline `\n` at the end of each `printk` statement.

Refer to this SO question to know why a newline is necessary:

- [Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)